# UserScript for removing some script tags

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, browser-extension

I want the UserScript which will remove all script tags (with some conditions) BEFORE then they will be loaded or executed.
I tried using DOMContentLoaded and onload events, but they are executed after loading script on page...

Comment: Thanks all! For Opera I find this http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/#BeforeScript

Answer (score 0):

I know with Tampermonkey you can use

```
// @run-at document-start
```

in the header of your script